# undefined: gomock.AssignableToTypeOf

Tags: go, bazel, bazel-rules, gomock, bazel-gazelle

I'm getting this error: ***undefined: gomock.AssignableToTypeOf***
It is occurring while using function gomock.AssignableToTypeOf of package github.com/golang/mock"

This starts occurring when I have Updated versions in the WORKSPACE file of Project, and the error which I'm getting while executing `bazel coverage` command is **undefined: gomock.AssignableToTypeOf**
Bazel Version: 4.2.1
Bazel Rules Version: v0.30.0
bazel_gazelle Version: v0.24.0
Go Version: 1.17.6
Docker Rules Version: 0.23.0

It was working fine on the previous versions --
Bazel Version: 3.7.1
Bazel Rules Version: v0.27.0
bazel_gazelle Version: v0.23.0
Go Version: 1.16
Docker Rules Version: 0.14.4

Here's the code snippet of the WORKSPACE file.

```
# Fetch Golang mock
go_repository(
    name = "com_github_golang_mock",
    # commit = "aba2ff9a6844d5e3289e8472d3217d5b3090f083",
    tag = "v1.6.0",
    importpath = "github.com/golang/mock",
)

go_repository(
    name = "go_googleapis",
    # commit = "aba2ff9a6844d5e3289e8472d3217d5b3090f083",
    tag = "v0.69.0",
    importpath = "github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client",
)

go_repository(
    name = "org_golang_google_genproto",
    tag = "v0.0.0-20220216160803-4663080d8bc8",
    importpath = "google.golang.org/genproto",
)

go_repository(
    name = "org_golang_x_mod",
    importpath = "golang.org/x/mod",
    tag = "v0.5.1",
)

go_repository(
    name = "org_golang_x_xerrors",
    importpath = "golang.org/x/xerrors",
    sum = "h1:/atklqdjdhuosWIl6AIbOeHJjicWYPqR9bpxqxYG2pA=",
    version = "v0.0.0-20191011141410-1b5146add898",
)

go_repository(
    name = "com_github_jmhodges_bazel_gomock",
    tag = "v1.3",
    importpath = "github.com/jmhodges/bazel_gomock",
)
```

Comment: Do not post images of text.

Comment: Duplicate of this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71153729/undefined-gomock-assignabletotypeof-while-using-github-third-party-package-git

Comment: Seems like an [issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_go/issues/3069) in bazelbuild/rules_go